# VictoriaMetrics, MetricsQL - Omit certain labels when computing aggregate function

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have a working Victoria Metrics query:

```
avg_over_time(label_1{label_id_1 = "123", label_id_2 = "456"} [100s])
```

This almost all the time returns one value (vector).
However, when the timeseries has a different version, it returns two values which is not desired.
Eg:

```
[
  {
    "metric": {
      "__name__": "label_1",
      "version": "1",
      "label_id_1": "123",
      "label_id_2": "456",
    },
    "value": [
      1710597352.247,
      "2986.54887451"
    ],
    "group": 1
  },
  {
    "metric": {
      "__name__": "label_1",
      "version": "2",
      "label_id_1": "123",
      "label_id_2": "456",
    },
    "value": [
      1710597352.247,
      "369872.158964"
    ],
    "group": 1
  }
]
```

Is there a way to compute the average without the `version` label so that I get back a single value every time?

The expected result should be this way (value here is arbitrary):

```
[
{
    "metric": {
      "__name__": "label_1",
      "label_id_1": "123",
      "label_id_2": "456",
    },
    "value": [
      1710597352.247,
      "12346579.46694"
    ],
    "group": 1
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two distinct time series in your data, and `version` label is what makes them distinct. You can't simply get rid of it. You need to decide how you want your rollup function to compute this:

1. Compute only one specific version: `avg_over_time(label_1{label_id_1="123",label_id_2="456",version="1"}[100s])`
2. Select max or min, or other [aggregation](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#aggregate-functions) across versions `avg(avg_over_time(label_1{label_id_1="123",label_id_2="456"}[100s])) without(version)`

Comment: Shouldn't `max` be inside of `avg_over_time`? I mean that in case of partial overlap of two series, `max` outside will produce somewhat unexpected results.

Comment: 1. The version here is dynamic and the service does not the version beforehand.
2. I'd need the average across all timeseries - wouldn't this just give back the max average value of the two distinct time series you mentioned?

Comment: ">  I'd need the average across all timeseries"      




Then try the following query: 
`avg(avg_over_time(label_1{label_id_1="123",label_id_2="456"}[100s])) without(version)`

Comment: Try playing with it on the playground here https://shorturl.at/loyAB

Comment: @hagen1778 Sorry, my math here is not great - Is the `avg` of `avg_over_time` value when there are multiple versions equal to the `avg_over_time` when there is just one version for the same timeseries values? 

I just want to make sure that the avg of avg_over_time is the right value and not a skewed one. For instance, if one version's avg_over_time is 0.5 and the other version's avg_over_time is 200, we will get back 100.25 as the final value. Is this right?

Comment: @underachiever, your math is correct in your example, result will be 100.25. But result in fact might be skewed (depending on what exactly you expect as a result). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78137902/21363224) for alternative points on calculating weighted average and points regarding average of the average.

Comment: @markalex Thanks, that's what I was wondering. Like how we do in a relational database, is there a way to group the timeseries by labels before applying a roll-up function? The `group()` function seems to be not working with the victoria metrics.

Comment: `any()` function actually groups the data but does not result in all the available timeseries values

Comment: > to group the timeseries by labels

When you group results in relational database, you still need to apply some form of aggregation.

Think of `avg_over_time` as "horizontal" aggregation in time. `avg_over_time(metrics_selector[interval])` will return the same number of series as `metrics_selector` would, but for each series samples will be aggregated on `interval`.

Think of `avg` as "vertical" aggregation. It aggregates data samples across all series satisfying `metrics_selector` in the same moment of time. Expression `avg(metrics_selector)` will return one series in response.

Comment: Apparently, this works - `avg_over_time(sum by(label_id_1, label_id_2) (label_1{label_id_1="123",label_id_2="456"}) [100s])